# Infer type of an object property based on object's sibling keys

Tags: typescript

Consider these array of objects:

```
  const inputGroup = [
{
    key: "primary_category",
    label: "Primary Category",
    elType: "select",
    elementConfig: {
      options: categories,
    },
  },
  {
    key: "extra_tags",
    label: "Extra tags",,
    elType: "input",
    elementConfig: {
      type: "text",
      placeholder: "e.g. startup, analytics, svelte, seo, social media,",
    },
  },
]
```

How would I type this so that `elementConfig`'s allowed properties depend on `elType`'s value?

Comment: Look up discriminated unions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a type that has the base properties (`key`, `label`) and intersect it with a union of two object types, one with `elType: "select"` and the relevant type for `elementConfig` for selects, and another with `elType: "text"` and the relevant type for `elementConfig` for text fields, like this:

```typescript
type GroupEntry =
    {
        key: string;
        label: string;
    } & (
        {
            elType: "select",
            elementConfig: {
                options: string; // Or whatever the type of `categories` should be
            }
        } |
        {
            elType: "input",
            elementConfig: {
                type: string; // Or maybe "text" | "number" | ...
                placeholder?: string;
            }
        }
    )
;
```

Then you declare your array of that type:

```typescript
const inputGroup: GroupEntry[] = [
    {
        key: "primary_category",
        label: "Primary Category",
        elType: "select",
        elementConfig: {
            options: "categories",
        },
    },
    {
        key: "extra_tags",
        label: "Extra tags",
        elType: "input",
        elementConfig: {
            type: "text",
            placeholder: "e.g. startup, analytics, svelte, seo, social media,",
        },
    },
    {
        key: "something",
        label: "stuff",
        elType: "select",
        elementConfig: {
            type: "text" // <==== Error as desired
        }
    }
];
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=22&ssc=1&pln=49&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBA4gTgewK5gKIDthxFAvAKCiKgG9DiKBrCEALigGcsBLdAcwG5yKiAbAQwBGEXvSZxWnblAC+UAGRQAFNIpkeGqCIAq4CPQBEDERADGwAwBpVmkwFsImAMIJ0AM2Zt66zb4RhgZlcGMRZ2DigAekioAHk4KAB3AAt+YAgANwgE4GToUEgoBDcoAANTNIg2BAkIBlLGZOReABMoYRsNGU7ZKAAfHp9fIh09Q1YwJAtrYeJ7R2AXd09vHt8C-UYwziiY+Kg7fhBhKAN0gA8LftP0JDthOANrgDpXtc0wAVMIJtbsgH5QhJwu8iN1fODiABKfBcfCmYLAKATKbwZBgeholAYLAgADaAF08FA8dIhjxqHRTmAJIdsAB9CrparYKw9ATCUSnAAKtP42CgTkqLJAbN8o0ghmMvDM0x682crg8XlIoKKASC6BCpyZVRqzDqYs0MhmxBNZJ6lMMEEucH49OA-DYDCNGg5IkMqFt-Cgjudrp4Es2BhRcvFMociuWKvJ6zGpwuYdmUE+-G+vxa2WtzzYzy2-OAKEsUH46H4vBAgVMDGLDCyvHStYgCFrCFMzHLBwgLQ7lgDFHNA9NRFjxCtpwYCAcuUk-eI7q5RkLbjcc5GvF0konJnMa60EYWS2Vq2TvvjZxtV2iUAAPLh77goKg4IgEvwGFBMwxmHBuz1IWC+AElwQA)